# Parse: After unsubscribe from channel I still receive push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an Android app that receive push notifications from [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) platform. It works properly but when I unsubscribe from a channel, I still receive notifications from this:

```
private void unsubscribe(String channel) {
    ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground(channel, new SaveCallback(){
        public void done(ParseException e ) {
            if (e == null) 
                success();
            else 
                failed();
        }
    });
}
```

`success()` method is called, then unsubscription process is righly performed.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This could be a problem in your Push Query. Can you add the query you use to target the recipient of a push?

Comment: omg, you are right. I was not specifying any target, so I was sending a broadcast. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Björn Kaiser, I have realized that the problem was not in the unsubscription but in sending push notification. I was sending a broadcast push, instead of targeted one by channel. A silly mistake.